# JAVA :How to Read file in Referenced Libraries

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi I was reading files using FileReader and Buffereader only and it was working perfectly

```
fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Bus_Station\\Bus station\\tripFile");          
br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

But I want to read put these files in somewhere so I put them in Referecnced Libraries so I can read from them on any machine without path but it is not working :/

```
(File file = new File("tripFile.txt");
file.createNewFile();
fr = new FileReader(file););
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use resources.

```
  URL fileURL = Resources.getResource("test.txt");
  String text = Resources.toString(fileURL, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

How to add a resources folder

[How do I add a resources folder to my Java project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934796/how-do-i-add-a-resources-folder-to-my-java-project-in-eclipse)

[adding resources in intellij for java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717038/adding-resources-in-intellij-for-java-project)

[How to create resource folder in Netbeans?](http://www.javaquery.com/2015/10/how-to-create-resource-folder-in.html)

Comment: rather intellij and netbeans you could provide project tree structure in eclipse and how to jar it

Comment: Use to maven resources tag , example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548997/maven-include-resources-into-jar