# Bundle Python.exe with Jar

Tags: java, python

I have created a Java application that executes a Python script using a runtime. I was wondering if there is a way to include the python.exe with the necessary libraries with the Jar file?

Comment: Since you're talking about the `exe` file, I suppose you're using Windows. Java was meant to be portable to different operating systems, and your application definitely won't be portable. If you need to execute a Python script at runtime, I'd advice you not to invent anything from scratch and just use the Jython project: https://www.jython.org

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem I've got is that I need to use python 3 which, as far as I'm aware, Jython doesn't support

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether it is the best option to bundle the windows specific python executable into your .jar file or if you want to use something like [jython](https://www.jython.org/) to execute python script from java.

But to answer your question this mainly depends on how you build your .jar file.
Are you using a build system like gradle/maven/ant or do you use an IDE to build it?

Here are some links for you on how to generally bundle assets/resources into a .jar.

#### Build systems

1. [Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724383/add-resources-config-files-to-your-jar-using-gradle)
2. [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548997/maven-include-resources-into-jar)
3. [Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216744/adding-non-code-resources-to-jar-file-using-ant)

#### IDEs

1. [IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887524/how-to-add-resource-file-to-jar-in-intellij)
2. [Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16633335)
3. [Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18092011)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem I have is I need python 3 for the libraries I'm using with, as far as I'm aware, jython doesn't support